# Info about version dependancies of enterprise java libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I am new to enterprise application developement and trying to create a REST server with Spring REST, JPA taking to mySQL database and Javascript on the client side. As I see loads of opensource libraries doing specific task, I started off with using 'maven project' with different 'arch type' (which is nothing but predefined POM with relevent libraries as I understand) provided by Eclipse. But I often run into version mismatch issues, in many cases found specific solution to that perticular libraries in StackOverflow or other sites.

Hence I started looking for a information these version dependancies such as, this version of JPA works with that version of Hibernate library and so on. I checked maven repository of major libraries, I did not find such information so far.

My queries are:

1. Where can I find these information about the versions dependancies?
2. Are these pre defined POM in eclipse reliable? Who owns them, where can I get last modified dates on these maven 'arch types'? (I find the ones I choose having fairly old version of libraries).
3. If I have to start off on my own creating a Maven dependacies, where will I get information about what are the dependent libraries, for example, if I need spring MVC, for sure it needs java servlet library. I am worried becuase the maven 'spring-mvc-jap' arch type whooping 50 libaries as dependancies.(Coming from embeded domain, I find to too hard to digest :D). So not sure if it is the right way.

Please correct if I am missing anything in my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this information, if you are using maven and some IDE you can go to the dependancy and make click un > and this will show the librarys used for this dependancy or if you want to use the console you have http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html this will show the same that the IDE.

After normally in the documentation of the library used, you can find some doc about the dependancy about this.

Other solution is get the .jar and use 7zip to see the POM and know the dependancy used.

And for finish my answer if the IDE tell you that you dont have x dependancy normally you have to add this because any of the other dependancy used have it (they used only for the compiling task), but sometime somes projet change a lots of code between the version .a to .b so you will have some problem using the version .b, at this moment i didnt find one good and easy way to fix this, only using the way that i told you (only if i found some problem in the compilation)

Comment: Thanks, this gives some leads, that dependadancy tree is helping. I've created POM on my own with required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

3> I am not sure how it works in eclipse but in IntelliJ IDEA when you start using some class without proper dependency IDEA suggest you to add proper dependency automatically. The same approach should be in eclipse.

Comment: But all these libraries shall be loaded in the path for IntelliJ, I presume, it might be pointing to repository of these libraries. In my case I am using Maven to do the job. Otherwise eclipse has no way of knowing existance of those classes.

Comment: Maven take libraries automatically from maven central repository. If you need some specific library you have to define specific repository in settings.xml http://maven.apache.org/settings.html